# Getting NullPointerException when using RemoteWebDriver from getWindowHandles()

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, selenium-chromedriver, remotewebdriver

When using RemoteWebDriver with ChromeDriver I get a `NullPointerException` when a new window is opened and `.getWindowHandle()` or `.getWindowHandles()` is called.

The following condition is satisfied:

```
ExpectedCondition<Boolean> windowCondition = new ExpectedCondition<Boolean>() {
        public Boolean apply(WebDriver driver) {
            return driver.getWindowHandles().size() != windowsBefore;
        }
    };
```

However, when the following is called I get the `NullPointerException`:

```
for (String handle : driver.getWindowHandles()) {
        driver.switchTo().window(handle);
    }
```

When running this script locally, I do not get the exception!

Comment: The NPE is in the `driver.switchTo().window(handle);` line or in the `for` clause?

Comment: It's in the for clause. I think I have solved it - I have it in a function that called driver without being passed the driver object. Changing this has resolved the issue! Cheers.